# Find position of multiple substrings R

Tags: r, search, position, substring

I am using R to find the position of multiple substrings within a larger string.  This is a fairly straight forward problem when I am only searching for one substring, but I need to use a function that finds ALL of the desired substrings.

For instance, I could have a vector like this:  "abcdefghijklmabcu".  I would want to find the position of the first occurrence of ab and the position of the second occurrence of ab.

I would appreciate any kind of help with this or the name of a package that would do this fairly easily.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share the code you have so far and why it isn't working.  As this question stands now, we are guessing at how far you've already come!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`regexpr` finds the first match just like `sub` replaces the first match.  adding a `g` to the front will find every match.

```
x <- 'abcdefghijklmabcu'
y <- gregexpr('ab', x)

regmatches(x, y)
```